# Preciso montar um array com os id's das checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso montar um array que tenha os id's dos checkbox que eu seleciona.
No código abaixo tenho um foreach que monta uma lista onde posso marcar o checkbox dela, eu gostaria de ter um array com os id's dos chackbox selecionados quando eu clicar no botão "Exportar".

```html
<div class="catalogo catalogo_index">
    <?php foreach ($categorias as $key_catagoria => $categoria): ?>
        <ul class="lista lista_roteiro_integral">
            <input name="check" type="checkbox" id="check_<?= $categoria->cat_id ?>" class="lista_item_poc_check"/>
            <li class="lista_item_poc"><p><b><?= $categoria->cat_titulo ?></b></p></li>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <a href="#" class="custom_button" id="exportar">Exportar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: E não esqueça de definir os valores dos *checkbox*...

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check[]" value="valor" checked/>
Segue o javascript e depois manda ele por ajax e pega o array como php
      <script>var meu_array     = $('input[name="check[]"]:checked').map(function(i, el) { return el.value;   }).get();</script>